# PyQt5 QTableWidget событие выделение ячейки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Есть ли у QTableWidget событие возникающее, когда перемещаешься клавишами вверх/вниз по таблице?
Что-то не могу найти.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Независимо от того как вы перемещаетесь стрелками или мышью испускается сигнал `itemSelectionChanged`.

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


def on_selection():
    print("Selection changed")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    widget = Qt.QTableWidget()
    widget.setRowCount(10)
    widget.setColumnCount(10)
    widget.itemSelectionChanged.connect(on_selection)

    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает.